# memset() vulnerability

Tags: c, security, embedded, memset

I am using memset in an embedded application to delete one data. here is the function:

```
uint8_t Delete()

{

    memset(cure.name, 0x0, 32);

    cure.volume = 0;

    cure.valid=0;

    printf("[*] Cure DELETED\n");

    return 1;

}
```

and I am trying to evaluate it against fault injection attack (clock glitching). As I saw in my experiments after clock glitching memset overwrites the neighbor's memory blocks as well. (they have been filled by zeros). is there any safer (more secure) alternative function for memset that I could use? maybe an instruction which validates the destination block at all the copying step.

Thank you in advance for your help;

Comment: You have to explain more how exactly you managed to get memset to misbehave. "Clock glitching" is kind of a broad term. What system is this, what MCU? Or is it a FPGA?

Comment: @Lundin : yes, this embedded code is running on cortex m3 processor. how ever it is a general fault effect, when it is processing some input, it can not finish the whole execution for an instruction like memset or it can not detect the end of memory block.

Comment: Would you mind to explain "clock glitching" and why you think it disturbes `memset()` in more detail, please? And what do you mean by "_it can not detect the end of memory block_"? Please add this new information to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: memset is a function call, not an instruction. What exactly is the connection between the MCU clock and this function?

Comment: from what I understand, clock glitching is a hardware attack.  What kind of "secure function" in software would you expect to protect against it?

Comment: memset is a standard library function; it is unlikely to take into consideration intentionally generated hardware glitches.  Since firmware protection against these glitches appears to depend on 1.  making the execution timing unpredictable, and by adding self-verification code.  I suspect you will have to write your own function to do this;you could add random delays within the loop for zeroing the memory, for example.  I am writing a comment, not an answer, as I do not know if this is sufficient.  You may need more details about what in your system is vulnerable; what instruction is targeted

Comment: @Basya  thank you for your help. yes, I agree with you, maybe random delay can help to reduce the impact of this kind of attack.

Comment: OK, so for the record I will submit it as an answer; if it works for you, please remember to come back and mark the answer as accepted.  If it does not help, perhaps if you explain why in a comment, someone here can help more.

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question. We don't know what is the type of `cure`, and on what target processor is the code supposed to run. Also give the compiler and compilation command you are using (perhaps some version -which one?- of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) configured as a cross-compiler).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - he is talking about robustness or vulnerability to a hardware attack.  How would you suggest he give us something reproduceable?  I am not sure how he would do that.

Comment: The C code should have a `main`, or, if it is free-standing code, a detailed explanation about starting points. In all cases, the type of `cure` should be explained

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - we still would not be able to reproduce the results.  From what I understand of the issue, none of the missing information is truly relevant to the question.  What would be relevant is information about what instruction was targeted in the hardware attack, but I am not sure the OP even knows that information.

Comment: But we would be able to read the C code and we might understand it. The given C code is not understandable (because type of `cure` is not known). E.g. if `cure` has a `char *name` field the code has undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memset is a standard library function; it is unlikely to take into consideration intentionally generated hardware glitches.
Firmware protection against these glitches appears to depend on:

1. making the execution timing unpredictable
2. adding self-verification code.

I suspect you will have to write your own function to do this; you could add random delays within the loop for zeroing the memory, for example.

I do not know if this is sufficient. You may need more details about what in your system is vulnerable; what instruction is targeted, in order to also add verification code

Comment: FYI, I found this page helpful: https://www.nuvoton.com/support/technical-support/technical-articles/TSNuvotonTechBlog-000154/